# Java Veracode Scan - False Positive on SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql-injection, veracode

We get an "CWE-89: Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection')" in the Java code:

```
    private static void doSomethingWithDB(int queryFetchSize, String sql, Object... params)
        try {
            Connection connection = ...

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setFetchSize(queryFetchSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                statement.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
            }
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); //this is where Veracode reports error
        ....
```

passing SQL from outside is not a best design practice but it is OK in this particular case (method is private, SQL queries are under our control).

How can I make Veracode less paranoid in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by **from outside** ? Who is constructing this `String sql` & is there any **user-input** or **untrusted source** involved  in getting this query constructed ?  method being `private` or `public` has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Comment: by **from outside** i mean call of this method from outside its class via some intermittent method like 
public static void fetchFromDB(String sql, Object... params) -> 

 doSomethingWithDB(queryFetchSize, sql, params);

The query is being constructed as String constant (**private static final String**), no user input or untrusted source

Comment: You need a meeting with your VeraCode consultant or tweak rules to ignore this error. I have experienced lots of false positives & usually I get exceptions added to rules after meeting with them.

Comment: Well, "tweak rules" AKA "add exception to rules" will mean that Veracode will miss the problem after code will be modified. 
Anyway, thank you for the help - it is better to know that "no viable solution exists" than not to ;-).

Comment: if code is dynamic so are rules :)  if you allow code changes without resetting rules, obviously there would be a problem. A tool malfunction needs to be fixed by tool company ( provided consultant doesn't have any  other explanation :) ) and not by developers so I don't see it as your concern.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario one workaround would be to pass the sql's identifier (e.g. enum) to the method instead of the sql itself, and then map this identifier to the actual sql inside the method body. So the example code would like something like this:

```
 private static void doSomethingWithDB(int queryFetchSize, SqlName sqlName, Object... params)
    try {
        Connection connection = ...

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SqlMap.get(sqlName));
        statement.setFetchSize(queryFetchSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            statement.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
        }
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    ....
```

*SqlName* is the enum representing your predefined sqls and *SqlMap* is the enum-keyed map definied somewhere else, containing actual sqls. With this solution, Veracode stops complaining about sql injection, which make sense to me as now you cannot use *any* sql in your method, only one you recognize.